# Perform row wise operation on two pandas columns

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have the following scenario.

```
import pandas as pd

d = {'col1': [1, 2, 3], 
     'col2': [['apple'], [], ['romaine', 'potatoes']], 
     'col3': [['orange', 'apple'], ['apple'], ['potatoes', 'collard']]
    }
df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)
```

So the dataframe is:

```
   col1   col2                   col3
0   1     [apple]                ['orange', 'apple']
1   2     []                     ['apple']
2   3     [romaine, potatoes]    ['potatoes', 'collard']
```

I want to create a third column as a combined list of unique values from columns col2 and col3. I want to do it in one line.

I have written a two-line solution:

```
df['col4'] = df['col2'] + df['col3']
df.col4 = df.col4.apply(list(set(lambda x: list(set(x)))
```

Leading to the expected outcome:

```
    col1    col2                col3                col4
0   1       [apple]             [orange, apple]     [orange, apple]
1   2       []                  [apple]             [apple]
2   3       [romaine, potatoes] [potatoes, collard] [collard, romaine, potatoes]
```

I wonder if there is a way to write a single line of code such as:

```
df['col4'] = df.col2.apply(lambda x: list(set(x + df.col3)))
```

The above code results in the following error:

> TypeError: Cannot broadcast np.ndarray with operand of type <class 'list'>

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try `apply` with `axis=1` on the whole dataframe (not just a column):

```
df['col4'] = df.apply(lambda x: list(set(x['col2'] + x['col3'])), axis=1)
```

Output:

```
   col1                 col2                 col3                          col4
0     1              [apple]      [orange, apple]               [apple, orange]
1     2                   []              [apple]                       [apple]
2     3  [romaine, potatoes]  [potatoes, collard]  [potatoes, collard, romaine]
```